# Transition not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make it so that you get an explanation of my project when you hover over the image.  If I set the span.text-content position to absolute, all of my list items align properly, but i get one box in the upper left corner and I can't see it at all once I scroll to lower images.

When I set the position to relative, it separates all of my images and the text box appears on the left side and below the image, but at least I get one for every image.  I've been playing with the z-index because, at first, you could only see the word "Explanation" as a sliver behind the top image.

Finally, my -o-transition won't gray out and I'm not sure what that's about?  I've checked jshint and I'm not throwing any errors.  Thanks in advance for the help!

**HTML**

```
    <li>
        <!--Dance Class-->
        <img src="images/dance.jpg" id="port-img" width="797px" height="307px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>


    <li>
        <!--That's Not Food-->
        <img src="images/tnf.png" id="port-img" width="797px" height="307px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <!--That's Not Food Pitch-->
        <img src="images/tnf-pitch.png" id="port-img" width="697px" height="500px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>


    <li>
        <!--Coaches Corner-->
        <img src="images/coach.jpg" id="port-img" width="697px" height="500px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <!--Singularity2045-->
        <img src="images/Singularity2045.png" id="port-img" width="697px" height="733px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <!--Overtime-->
        <img src="images/overtime.png" id="port-img" width="697px" height="500px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

</ul>



 **CSS:**

     span.text-content {
    /* allows me to adjust the filters and transparency of the outer span/image */
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: table;
      font-size: 1.5em;
      height: 300px;
      left: 0;
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 500px;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
      -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
      -o-transition: opacity 500ms; 
      transition: opacity 500ms;
      z-index: 1;
}

span.text-content span {
    /* For text alignment */
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

    ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content{
        opacity: 1;
    }

     #port-img{
         z-index: 1;
         position: relative;
         top: 69px

     }
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample or codepen so we can see it? I'm not sure I'm picturing quite what you're explaining. Also, you mentioned -o-transition. Is the issue specifically in Opera?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This will help getting useful answers

Comment: @user5775386 No, not Opera-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWPpQZ

**HTML**

```
<ul class="img-list">

    <li>
        <!--Dance Class-->
        <img src="images/dance.jpg" class="port-img" width="797px" height="307px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>
<li>
        <!--That's Not Food-->
        <img src="images/tnf.png" class="port-img" width="797px" height="307px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <!--That's Not Food Pitch-->
        <img src="images/tnf-pitch.png" class="port-img" width="697px" height="500px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>


    <li>
        <!--Coaches Corner-->
        <img src="images/coach.jpg" class="port-img" width="697px" height="500px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <!--Singularity2045-->
        <img src="images/Singularity2045.png" class="port-img" width="697px" height="733px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <!--Overtime-->
        <img src="images/overtime.png" class="port-img" width="697px" height="500px"/>
        <span class="text-content"><span>Explanation</span></span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-content {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms; 
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.text-content span {
  display: block;
  /* For text alignment */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.img-list li:hover .text-content{
  opacity: 1;
}

 .port-img{
   display: block;
 }
```

**Explanation**

Changed id="port-img" to class as you should not have multiple elements with same id.

Anyway the most important part is that li element have position relative so all child elements positioned absolutely are positioned to each li element.

Different way to position text verticaly is used as it was easier to make explanation box 100% height.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because your solution works perfectly on CodePen.  I've copied it exactly and all I can see on my page now is a very large box that says "Explanation" in the center of it when I hover over the page.  

If I scroll down the page, I can't get that.  I changed some of the image text to test it and still only see "Explanation." All of my images completely disappeared  the moment I added "img-list li" to the code.

All of this tells me the problem is further up in my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Shelly do you have
`li {
  position: relative;
}` ? also note that if you have other li elements on page it would be better to add some class to those that you want be affected and change li to that class selector.

Comment: Yes, I have that code and I had classes because my navMenu is also an li.  BUT, I didn't have the syntax for the class correct.  Forgot the "."!  So, thanks for that; my pictures have reappeared.  I'll have to revisit the code and see if I can get it working (no time, atm).